# Is there a standalone, portable command line implementation of Mustache for windows?

Tags: mustache

Is there a simple, standalone, portable, existing distribution of Mustache for windows that lets me invoke Mustache exactly as specified (or as close as possible) in the [mustache(1)](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.1.html) manual?

```
cat data.yml template.mustache | mustache
```

I can't find any explanation of how to actually acquire an executable called `mustache` to *use* mustache in this way - on any platform, although I'm primarily interested in Windows right now.

As far as I can tell, the various implementations of mustache listed on the mustache homepage are mostly libraries, rather than standalone applications that can be invoked in this way.

Ideally, I'm looking for something that's:

- **Standalone** - I am looking for something I can invoke from the command line, not a library. I am planning to generate output as part of my automated CI build.
- **Portable** - I should be able to bundle everything I need into source control, without having to preinstall anything (since my build may run on one of many build agents, I do not wish to maintain a suite of preinstalled software on multiple agents); nor can I connect to the internet to download libraries. Ideally the portable packaging should be fairly straightforward to bundle.

If this isn't available then I'm interested in getting as close as possible - e.g. if I have to preinstall python but *not* needing to run an installer which connects to the internet.

I'm prepared to concede on the "no preinstall" if it's something I have a cat in hell's chance of already having packaged up at our organisation (e.g. python or ruby) but not for individual libraries.

Comment: On reflection I'm actually happy with _any_ free/OSS template language that fulfils these criteria!

Comment: `mustache` is a command line tool that can be installed with `gem install mustache`. Not sure how it match your concession on the "no preinstall", but it might help.

Comment: Thanks. There is probably _some_ way to make that portable, though it needs a lot of overhead (I don't generally have ruby/gem on my win servers).

Answer (score 2):

(Full disclosure: I am the maintainer of this project.)

I have written [mo](https://github.com/tests-always-included/mo), which is a Bash port of the mustache templating system.  Its major caveat is that it uses environment variables instead of reading from a `.json` file.

```
$ export name="John Doe"
$ cat template.mo
Hello {{name}}.
{{^name2}}The variable name2 is not defined.{{/name2}}
$ mo template.mo
Hello John Doe.
The variable name2 is not defined.
```

It also works with arrays, but Bash can not export arrays to other functions.  So, to have arrays work you will need to either source another file or source `mo` itself into the environment and then call the `mo` function.

The repository contains tests and examples to help illustrate how to use this tool.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> INSTALLATION
>
> If you have RubyGems installed:
>
> gem install mustache

See https://mustache.github.io/mustache.1.html
bottom of page

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use one of the implementations of Mustache that compiles to a native executable. For instance, here are the pre-compiled releases for the [Go client](https://github.com/cbroglie/mustache/releases).

Thus installing to a Linux server could look something like:

```
GO_MUSTACHE_VERSION=1.2.0
curl -s -L -o /tmp/mustache.tgz https://github.com/cbroglie/mustache/releases/download/v${GO_MUSTACHE_VERSION}/mustache_${GO_MUSTACHE_VERSION}_linux_amd64.tar.gz
tar xvf /tmp/mustache.tgz -C path/to/installation
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have Groovy installed on your Windows machine you can just run this script: https://gist.github.com/agentgt/1bc5f14e62bce11e2ceb . You do not need to download anything else as the script will automatically download the correct dependencies so no dep hell.

The Groovy version is slightly more cross platform (although one could argue about that) than the Ruby version albeit it requires Java and is slower. If your a JVM shop this is usually not a problem.

You could take the above script and turn it into Java and create single executable Jar with all the dependencies that will work anywhere Java is installed. If interested just add a comment and I'll make a quick project.