# Is there an easy way to integrate Mustache template engine into a Windows build system?

Tags: windows, command-line, build, integration, mustache

I want to add scripts to a gmake-driven Windows build system so that it can generate various templated output files (e.g. code, internal documentation, external documentation) from a single source script. A decade ago, I'd have used XML + DTD + XSLT, but now I'd like to use the Mustache template engine instead (which doesn't have all the enterprise baggage).

However... even though the template language side of the Mustache equation rocks the house, I can't quite see how best to integrate the data side into a typical gmake-style Windows build. Passing lumps of JSON to Handlebars.js is fine on a webserver, but I'd really like a lightweight command-line-centric Mustache template instantiation that's not going to annoy everyone who's using the build.

I've looked at Pystache/Python and Text::Caml/Perl, but they seem a bit too idiosyncratic. I guess what I'm hoping for is some kind of 'pure' JSON + Mustache command-line tool, but I'm really not seeing it out there. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Finally: I should add that I do know that the recommended way to install Mustache is to install Ruby + devkit, and then gem install mustache, so that you can feed YAML to a command-line Mustache executable. But that's 132MB of download, and I would get a certain amount of resistance if I suggested we install Ruby + MSYS2 + everything else just to run a 'lightweight' template engine under Windows. :-(

Comment: I guess this is a slight superset of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625582/is-there-a-standalone-portable-command-line-implementation-of-mustache-for-wind

Comment: The least idiosyncratic / closest-to-YAML implementation I've found is Lua + https://luapower.com/mustache . Only 29MB download!

Comment: The closest pure C implementation seems to be Fletcher Penney's Magnum, though the next step would seem to be to try to build it for Windows via MSYS2: https://github.com/fletcher/magnum

Comment: Fletcher Penney included code in Magnum to cross-compile it for Windows under mingw. However, you can also build it directly under MSYS2 on Windows:

make release
cd build
make

Having said that, it's not (I believe) so straightforward to run the test suite under Windows, because that relies on .sh shell scripts to generate the test code etc. But it looks as though MSYS2 is working fine.